# Backtracking segmentation fault error in gfg problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, segmentation-fault, backtracking

[https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rat-in-a-maze-problem/1/?category[]=Backtracking&category[]=Backtracking&page=1&query=category[]Backtrackingpage1category[]Backtracking#](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rat-in-a-maze-problem/1/?category%5B%5D=Backtracking&category%5B%5D=Backtracking&page=1&query=category%5B%5DBacktrackingpage1category%5B%5DBacktracking#)

```
void pathfinder(vector<vector<int>> m, int r, int c, int n, string s, vector<string> &v, 
                vector<vector<int>> &store){
    if(r==n-1 && c==n-1){
        v.push_back(s);
        return;
    }
    
    if(r<0 || c<0 || r>=n || c>=n || m[r][c]==0 || store[r][c]==1)
        return;
    
    store[r][c]=1;
    pathfinder(m, r-1, c, n, s+'U', v, store);
    pathfinder(m, r+1, c, n, s+'D', v, store);
    pathfinder(m, r, c-1, n, s+'L', v, store);
    pathfinder(m, r, c+1, n, s+'R', v, store);
    store[r][c]=0;
}

vector<string> findPath(vector<vector<int>> &m, int n) {
    // Your code goes here
    
    string s="";
    vector<string> v;
    vector<vector<int>> store;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<n; ++j){
            store[i][j]=0;   
        }
    }
    
    pathfinder(m, 0, 0, n, s, v, store);
    return v;
}
```

this is my solution, but I'm facing error as segmentation fault. Tired for nearly 1:30 hours, please check where the code is wrong.

Comment: If you are having hard-to-trace segfaults, consider a tool like `valgrind`, maybe...

Comment: You'd better avoid that gfg garbage collection unless you want to learn how to write really bad C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Your **store** vector hasn't been assigned a size before its usage. You can assign it's size using the following first:

```
vector<vector<int>> store( n , vector<int> (n));
```

This creates a 2D vector of size n x n

Answer (score 0):

These lines :

```
vector<vector<int>> store;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<n; ++j){
            store[i][j]=0;   
        }
```

Here, you have not allocated memory before accessing it like array. `2d` vector has `size 0`. First allocate memory using `push_back()` or initialise vector with size `n x n`.

Comment: Push_back is not ideal, it gives too many reallocations.

Comment: @Surt I was just pointing out his purpose of using `for loop`. In this case it's not ideal as he's initialising with same data. But when he wants to initialize with user input data then there's no other option.